# Why do Redshift COPY queries use (much) more disk space for tables with a sort key

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a large set of data on S3 in the form of a few hundred CSV files that are ~1.7 TB in total (uncompressed).  I am trying to copy it to an empty table on a Redshift cluster.

The cluster is empty (no other tables) and has 10 dw2.large nodes.  If I set a sort key on the table, the  copy commands uses up all available disk space about 25% of the way through, and aborts.  If there's no sort key, the copy completes successfully and never uses more than 45% of the available disk space.  This behavior is consistent whether or not I also set a distribution key.

I don't really know why this happens, or if it's expected.  Has anyone seen this behavior?  If so, do you have any suggestions for how to get around it?  One idea would be to try importing each file individually, but I'd love to find a way to let Redshift deal with that part itself and do it all in one query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got an answer to this from the Redshift team.  The cluster needs free space of at least 2.5x the incoming data size to use as temporary space for the sort.  You can upsize your cluster, copy the data, and resize it back down.

Comment: 2.5x the size of the incoming data? That seems ridiculous. It's not some constant times the number of rows you're inserting, but it actually is dependent on the size of the rows?

Comment: We also had major problems with this. Our cluster was at 40% disk use at the start of the import and would go all the way to 100% and sometimes even crash the import, which seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Each dw2.large box has 0.16 TB disk space. When you said you you have cluster of 10 nodes, total space available is around 1.6 TB.
You have mentioned that you have around 1.7 TB raw data ( uncompressed) to be loaded in redshift.

When you load data to redshift using copy commands redshift automatically compresses you data and load it table.
once you load any db table you can see compression encoding by below query

```
Select "column", type, encoding 
from pg_table_def where tablename = 'my_table_name'
```

Once you load your data when table has no sort key. See what are compression are being applied.
I suggested you drop and create table each time when you load data for your testing So that compressions encoding will be analysed each time.Once you load your table using copy commands see below link and fire script to determine table size

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_analyzing-table-design.html

Since when you apply sort key for your table and load data , sort key also occupies some disk space.

Since table with out sort key need less disk space than table with sort key.

You need to make sure that compression are being applied to table.

When we have sort key applied it need more space to store. When you apply sort key you need to check if you are loading data in sorted order as well,so that data will be stored in sorted fashion. This we need to avoid **vacuum** command to sort table after data being loaded.