# Increasing disk usage during Redshift loads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

**Context**

- I'm currently working with a relatively small data set on a single node dw2.large Redshift cluster
- The current data set is ~9 gb (compressed)/90m rows
- Data is loaded into the Redshift cluster about once/hour
- Only one load is ever run at a time
- The size of incoming data varies, but it's reasonable to assume it's mostly consistent across this sample
- A `VACUUM` query is run once/day

**Problem**

I'm seeing disk usage *during* Redshift loads increase faster than I'd expect. If you look at the first chart below (disk usage by minute) you can see a band of disk usage.  The bottom edge is the "actual" size of the data set and the top edge is the peak data usage during loads.  The second chart shows disk usage by hour — the same data set, but with the peaks from loads smoothed out.

The peaks and the base are growing at the same rate.  In other words, the peak disk usage during load seems to be mostly a function of the total data size, not the incoming data size.

Loads are performed roughly like [this merge strategy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-replacing-existing-rows.html).  Specifically, it uses these steps:

1. Begin transaction
2. Create a temp table with the same schema as the real table
3. Run a `COPY` query to import data from Redshift (using `JSON`, `GZIP` and `MANIFEST` options)
4. Delete data from temp table that is already duplicated in the real table
5. Delete data that is duplicated within the temp table
6. Load data into the real table using `INSERT INTO` (this diverges slightly from the Redshift documentation by using an explicit column list, because the tables use `IDENTITY` fields)
7. Drop the temp table
8. End transaction

**Questions**

- Is it expected that peak disk usage would grow proportionally to the total data size?  If so, that's concerning because an increasingly large portion of the cluster's disk is seemingly going to be "wasted".
- Are there any strategies to load data in a way that won't follow this pattern?  I've tried loading data less frequently (used to happen once every 10 minutes), which you can see in the later part of the first chart where there's more whitespace between the peaks.  This doesn't seem to have any effect.

[image: Disk usage by minute]
[image: Disk usage by Hour]

Comment: Are you using some encoding for your columns?

Comment: Are you using vacuum after load? I believe you missed this point in your description. This is only one possible reason for such behavior. I am unable to reproduce your case.

Comment: @Guy all of the columns use encoding

Comment: @YuriLevinsky VACUUM is run once/day (mentioned in the "context" section above)

Answer (score 0):

When you use copy command Redshift requires additional space to perform sort. This causing temporary peak of space usage. 9gb is meaningless for RedShift that is targeted to work with terabytes of dat. When you will work with serious data amount the picture will be different: you will still see the peaks but not a twice of total data.

Comment: I've asked the Redshift team specifically about disk space used for sorts. The advice they've given me is that sorts will use "at least" 2.5x the incoming data size (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332738/why-do-redshift-copy-queries-use-much-more-disk-space-for-tables-with-a-sort-k/26447065#26447065).  The concerning thing isn't the amount of disk used, it's the pattern of how it's changing.